# MEAN stack - sorting by date is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, mean

I have been trying to `sort` my records according to date and time. But my result is not being sorted as expected.

I am storing time in MongoDB using the `new Date()` -

`let timestamp = new Date();`

Here is the query which results `ordered` and `paginated` documents -

```
Product.find({})
    .sort({created_time: sortDirection})
    .skip(pageSize * pageNumber)
    .limit(pageSize)
    .select('name price currency bot_enabled created_time')
    .exec();
```

Here `sortDirection` is either `1` or `-1` from conditional logic. All other functions of `find()` are working fine except the `sort({created_time: sortDirection})`. It is working but can't sort according to date and time.

Am I missing anything in my code?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is my collection structure -

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: String,
  currency: String,
  description: String,
  bot_enabled: Boolean,
  created_time: String
}, { versionKey: false });
```

Comment: What does `sortDirection` contains? And can you show how your collection looks like

Comment: `sortDirection` is either `1` or `-1`. Added collection structure in my question @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: It should work. I cannot see anything wrong

Answer (score 1):

Make your "created_time" field type "Date" like as bellow.

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: String,
  currency: String,
  description: String,
  bot_enabled: Boolean,
  created_time: Date
}, { versionKey: false });
```

This may not work in your old data but after changes schema field type and store Date in date format then this will work.